# How to get only searched word as a result python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How can I get only the words that match my regex in python? Because everything I tried also prints the full line where the string was found.

The regex is the following:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\/([0-9]{1,2})\b
```

It matched IP + CIDR (e.g 12.0.0.0/8)

The text in which I am searching this is as follows:

```
04/30","172.18.186.0/24","172.18.185.0/24","172.18.177.16/28","dwefwf-1.RI-nc_wefwfwefwefpat_intweb_fe","172.18.176.16/28","edefwfwf
t_pat_infwef_fe","172.18.178.16/28","dwefwefwef-wefwffwefwefwef_dr_efwefeb_fe","172.18.176.80/28","DSwefwfH2. 
RI-nc_rat_dr_fweweb_fe","172.18.178.48/28","172.18.177.208/28","wefwef 
wefwtfweapp_fe","172.18.176.208/28","wfwfwefwefwefH2.RI-nwefwefdr_app_fe","172.18.177.192/28","de1dfwwf-1.wefewf","172.18.176.1
92/28","
```

Comment: can you put what you've tried? your regex looks OK, though it's going to output each tuple piece as a separate match, and you probably want a group around all of it (with (?:) for the inside ones), so it's hard to tell why it returns the whole string.

Comment: use group: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your `regex` as follows:

`\b(([1-9][0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\/([0-9]{1,2}))\b`

and then extract the first matched group: `\1`

Demo: http://repl.it/R0W/1 (It takes a while to run)

Comment: It has to pass 1 minute before I can do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your regexp work correctly. If you want to get matched string use [`group`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) function. Like this:

```
import re

regexp = r'\b([1-9][0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\/([0-9]{1,2})\b'

text = '''04/30","172.18.186.0/24","172.18.185.0/24","172.18.177.16/28","dwefwf-1.RI-nc_wefwfwefwefpat_intweb_fe","172.18.176.16/28","edefwfwf
t_pat_infwef_fe","172.18.178.16/28","dwefwefwef-wefwffwefwefwef_dr_efwefeb_fe","172.18.176.80/28","DSwefwfH2. 
RI-nc_rat_dr_fweweb_fe","172.18.178.48/28","172.18.177.208/28","wefwef 
wefwtfweapp_fe","172.18.176.208/28","wfwfwefwefwefH2.RI-nwefwefdr_app_fe","172.18.177.192/28","de1dfwwf-1.wefewf","172.18.176.1
92/28","'''

for i in re.finditer(regexp, text):
    print i.group(0)
```

Comment: Awesome, so I don't even have to edit my original regex! Thank you! Too bad I can't pick 2 answers :(